# Binding to a non class variable fails in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Given a sample ContentPage

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage, IViewFor<MyPageModel> //ReactiveContentPage<MyPageModel>
{
    Entry input;
    //Entry input2;
    Label displayLabel;
    Slider _slider;
    Button _button;
    ListView _listView;
    public MyPage() : base()
    {
        ViewModel = new MyPageModel();

        input = new Entry();
        var input2 = new Entry();
        displayLabel = new Label();
        _slider = new Slider();
        _button = new Button { Text = "Save" };
        _listView = new ListView();
        var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "name");
        cell.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "location");
        _listView.ItemTemplate = cell;

        //_listView.ItemsSource = ViewModel.monkeys;
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" },
                input, input2,
                displayLabel,
                _slider,
                _button,
                _listView
            }
        };

        this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.username, x => x.input.Text);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.username, x => input2.Text); //error line 
        this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.value, x => x._slider.Value);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.monkeys, x => x._listView.ItemsSource);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.save, x => x._button.Command);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.value, x => x.displayLabel.Text);
    }
```

The above will not compile. It gives the exception below. When input2 is a property of the class, it runs just fine. Also, OneWayBind will not even compile at all.

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Unsupported expression type: 'Constant'
  Source=ReactiveUI
  StackTrace:
       at ReactiveUI.ExpressionMixins.GetExpressionChain(Expression This)
       at ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin.SubscribeToExpressionChain[TSender,TValue](TSender source, Expression expression, Boolean beforeChange, Boolean skipInitial)
       at ReactiveUI.WhenAnyMixin.WhenAnyDynamic[TSender,TRet](TSender This, Expression property1, Func`2 selector)
       at ReactiveUI.PropertyBinderImplementation.Bind[TViewModel,TView,TVMProp,TVProp,TDontCare](TViewModel viewModel, TView view, Expression`1 vmProperty, Expression`1 viewProperty, IObservable`1 signalViewUpdate, Object conversionHint, IBindingTypeConverter vmToViewConverterOverride, IBindingTypeConverter viewToVMConverterOverride)
       at ReactiveUI.BindingMixins.Bind[TViewModel,TView,TVMProp,TVProp](TView view, TViewModel viewModel, Expression`1 vmProperty, Expression`1 viewProperty, Object conversionHint, IBindingTypeConverter vmToViewConverterOverride, IBindingTypeConverter viewToVMConverterOverride)
       at App5.MyPage..ctor()
       at App5.App..ctor()
       at App5.WinPhone.MainPage..ctor()
  InnerException:
```

- Is this by design or am I doing something wrong here?
- Though it does not run, why does that code compile with `Bind` but not `OneWayBind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by-design, you'll have to use a property for two-way binds.

Comment: Ok. I was looking at a scenario where the data passed to a page is actually of list of objects from which it creates the various ui elements. Since these ui element (label, entry, etc) are created within the look, they cannot be made part of the class fields or properties. Is there any way around this or I will have to just rethink my design :) ?

Comment: You'll have to rethink it if you want two-way binds. However, I'd allege that you probably only really want binding From the TextView To the VM, so you can use `WhenAny().BindTo()` which works with arbitrary values

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently playing around with xamarin and ReactiveUI so decided to checkout the source code. I got it working after modifying some 9 classes :). My controls don't have to be part of the main class. I will keep refining and testing it some more but will stick to the default design for no-trivial apps.